# jQuery -> mod_ruby querystring

Tags: jquery, ruby, query-string

I have mod_ruby running on my apache2 server and am attempting to use jQuery to run a ruby script which will present data back to the client based on the information it receives, this is my first time working with mod_ruby, I am not running rails as it is completely overkill for this simple function, and PHP is dog slow at what I need to do.

With jQuery's .get() I can get the results of the script with:

```
$.get('get.rbx',{ type:"client", id:"someusername" }, function(data,status){ }
```

which will send this to the server:

```
https://myserver.com/get.rbx?type=client&id=someusername
```

Does anyone know how I can glean this querystring in ruby so that I can make use of the request data?

Comment: PHP is dog slow and you decided to use ruby? I have bad news for you. :)

Comment: it is for what I need the script to do because my ruby script reaches out to a few other systems via ssh and ruby is very quick at that but with php I have to build in all kinds of sleep timers while I wait for data.